# Why am I not getting correct result when I calculate exponent with ^ in C++?

Tags: c++

I am using Bode's formuala to calculate distance of nth planet from sun

```
dist = (4 + 3*(2^(n-2)))/10
```

If I calculate the distance this way, I get the right values:

```
dist[2] = ((4 + 3*1)/10.0) ;  
dist[3] = ((4 + 3*2)/10.0) ;  
dist[4] = ((4 + 3*4)/10.0) ;
```

But doing it this way, gives me incorrect values:

```
vector <double> dist(5);  

for (unsigned int i = 2; i < 5; i++)  
{  
    dist[i] = ((4 + 3*(2^(3-2)))/10.0) ;  
}
```

Why so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `^` character represents a bitwise exclusive or, not the exponential function that you expect.

Since you're calculating this in a loop already you can easily generate the powers of 2 that you need in the equation, something simple (and close to your code) would be:

```
vector<double> dist(5);
unsigned int j = 1;
for(unsigned int i = 2; i < 5; i++){
    dist[i] = (4+3*j)/10.0;
    j = j * 2;
}
```

In this particular instance, we initialize `j` to the first value of `n-2` that you require, then proceed to multiply it by 2 to get the next power of 2 that you require.

Answer (score 7):

Because `^` is not the power operator in C++. You can use `std::pow` but with `double` or you can do a lot of casting to make it work with `int`.

Answer (score 5):

First off:

```
dist[i] = ((4 + 3*(2^(3-2)))/10.0) ;
```

Is constant. I believe you meant to do the following:

```
dist[i] = ((4 + 3*(pow(2, (i-2)))/10.0) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

For one, there's ^ means "xor", not "power of". For another, you're calculating a constant value (You did `3-2` instead of `i-2`). However, since you want a power of two, bit-shifting can work your way. ("1 << X" works out as "2^X")

```
vector <double> dist(5);

for (unsigned int i = 2; i < 5; i++) {
   dist[i] = ((4 + 3*(1 << (i - 2)))/10.0) ;
}
```

For other bases, you need the pow() library function found in `<math.h>`/`<cmath>` (C/C++, respectively).

Comment: "For other bases, you need the pow()" ...that's simply not true.

Comment: Well, assuming you don't pull off the exponentiation yourself through iteration, yes. Oversight of mine.

Answer (score 1):

The `^` operator, in C++ (and several other languages) means "exclusive or", **not** "raise to power".

C++ does not have a "raise to power" operator; you need to use the 2-argument function `pow` (you can `#include` the old C-generation `<math.h>`, or `#include <cmath>` and use `std::pow`), which returns a `double`; or, as other answers have suggested, for this special case you might use bit-shifting.